# Can an alternate Effect have the Reaction extra?

Tags: character-creation, balance, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I've been playing around with making a Kung-Fu master for some time in *Mutants and Masterminds*, and I'm nearly done. However, I'm not sure if I constructed their attacks correctly. The image that I had in my head was that he'd be able to smack people upside the head if they failed to hit him, while also being able to hit with devastating effect if he was able to concentrate on *where* he hit.

This was what I came up with:

*Multi Attack Damage 5 -linked- Weaken(Fighting[Fort Save]) 10 -Linked- Affliction(Fort Save) 5*

*Alternate*

*Reaction, Multi Attack Damage 5*

**Is this correct? If it is, how does the power function?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, this power works. You choose which one you're using each round.

According to the section on Alternate Effects in the DC Adventures Hero's Handbook, you can only have one power from an array active at a time, and you can switch between active powers as a free action once per round.

> Alternate Effects cannot be used or maintained at the same time as other Alternates in the same array; they are mutually exclusive. Switching between Alternates requires a free action and can be done once per turn.

As a result, yes, you could choose to have a Reaction effect as an Alternate Effect, but you generally can't use it in the same round as when you use any other Effects in the array.

Comment: thanks for the input. I thought it would turn out something like this, but what can ya do? I think im just gonna separate the two powers, reduce the first to just damage and the second to 3 damage. Still, its great to get an answer in such a timely manner